# Changing default json for an object in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

- I have a simple Spring Boot Application having a simple MyDateTime model class only having a java.util.Date instance variable with private access, getters/setters and default constructor.
- A controller just instantiates this object and returns back.
- In the output, I see that default representation of Date object is done as an Integer (maybe millis from Epoch)
- Is there any way I can change the default jsonification of Date Object into ISO-String or any other String?

EDIT:

### Some Clarification:

I'm very new to Spring and Spring Boot. I'm using the template from a sample application on spring's website. JSONification is done through Jackson. Rest, I don't know much about Spring in general.

Comment: Can you please share some code? How do you print your MyDateTime model?

Comment: I'm not printing anything. I simply have a Class called SimpleController which instantiates another class MyDateTime and returns it.

Comment: How is this related to Spring Boot? When/Why/How do you create the JSON? What JSON API do you use? This question lacks any of the necessary information required to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the default format Jackson uses when serializing dates in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

You can also specify a specific format to use for a specific date using the `@JsonFormat` annotation, example below:

Example POJO:

```
public class Demo {
    private Date timestamp1;
    private Date timestamp2;
    public Date getTimestamp1() {
        return timestamp1;
    }
    public void setTimestamp1(Date timestamp1) {
        this.timestamp1 = timestamp1;
    }
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    public Date getTimestamp2() {
        return timestamp2;
    }
    public void setTimestamp2(Date timestamp2) {
        this.timestamp2 = timestamp2;
    }
}
```

Example Controller:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Demo start() {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        Date timestamp = new Date();
        demo.setTimestamp1(timestamp);
        demo.setTimestamp2(timestamp);
        return demo; 
    }
}
```

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Answer (score 0):

`Date.toString()` method returns epoch timestamp by default. What you want to do is about Jackson internals. To accomplish that, change your `MyDateTime` class to something like this:

```
public class MyDateTime {
    private final Date date;

    public MyDateTime(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date date() {   //this is not read by Jackson
        return date;
    }

    public String getDate() {   //this is read by Jackson
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return formatter.format(date);
    }

}
```

When serializing, Jackson look for getter methods, the methods that start with `get`. If you don't want something to be serialized, remove `get` from the name. This is the simplest solution, you can check Jackson API for [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) annotation for further solutions. If you want to see something other `date` in the field name in JSON string, look for [@JsonProperty](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html).

To print human readable date, you need `SimpleDateFormat`. 
The examples works fine on my setup, I did not do anything further than returning custom class from `HelloController`.